# Condition to perform the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda

There is a function that counts the moving average of the Y column:

```
df['Y1'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: df.loc[
        (
            (df.X2 < x.X2)
            & (df.X2 >= (x.X2 + pd.DateOffset(days=-4)))
            & (df.X3 == x.X3)
            & (df.X4 == x.X4)
        ),
        "Y",
    ].mean(),
    axis=1,
)
```

How can I enter the condition X5 = 1, under which this function would be executed.
If X5 = 1, then we calculate the average, if not Y1 remains empty.

I will clarify, talking about the value of X5 in the current line.

Comment: Add the appropriate tag if this is related to pandas.

Comment: Y1 should be the average of what?

Comment: Y column.For each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap this in an if-else:

```
lambda x: np.nan if X5 != 1 else df.loc[
    (
        (df.X2 < x.X2)
        & (df.X2 >= (x.X2 + pd.DateOffset(days=-4)))
        & (df.X3 == x.X3)
        & (df.X4 == x.X4)
    ),
    "Y",
].mean(),
```

Comment: Thank! Another clarification. This will make Y1 = NaN, but how can i do Y1 = Y1? Not empty, but equal to the current value.

Comment: @asymon use `x['Y1']` instead of np.nan should do it